# Unable to download Block Blob with DownloadToFileAsync method C#

Tags: c#, azure, download, blob

I am trying to download a block blob from Azure using C#. The code I am using is below.

In other tests, I am able to list the blobs in the container but I am unable to download a specific blob. It doesn't give me an exception or error but the file when created locally is empty.

I have cleared out the connection string for obvious reasons.

Does my code look ok?

```js
var containerName = "samples-workitems";

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.windows.net");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

try {
  CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("file.png");
  var localPath = string.Format("C:\\users\\user\\downloads\\file.png");



  blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(localPath, FileMode.Create);
  
  catch
  {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You know what - I have been stuck on this since yesterday and since posting this 2 minutes ago - I removed...

```js
  CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("file.png");
  var localPath = string.Format("C:\\users\\user\\downloads\\file.png");
```

these 2 lines of code from within the try statement and put them above it. It now works?!

Why is that?

Comment: One possible reason could be that you're not awaiting the async operation (`DownloadToFileAsync`) to complete. You would need to `await` that.

Comment: use :-    await blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(localPath , FileMode.Create);